# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar una imagen .web en html?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo la necesidad de visualizar imágenes con formato .web en mi html pero la etiqueta  no me funciona, doy gracias de antemano, lo estoy intentando de esta forma :

```
<img src="../Content/images/20211028_1ca.webp" style="padding:3px;" width="100px" height="100px" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe ser definitivamente un problema de rutas. Verifica la dirección de la imagen .webp, por que como podrás ver acá, el formato no tiene nada que ver.

Solo puse una imagen .webp en el source, y todo está correcto.

```html
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp" style="padding:3px;" width="100px" height="100px" alt="">
```